# Why does this SQL statement fail when two columns share the same LIKE statement?

Tags: php, sql, web

```
<?php
$search_input = $_POST["search_input"];

include_once("connection_to_db.php");

if(!isset($search_input))
{
    print("Nothing to search !");
    return;
}

//Queries products where the search input is similiar to the title, artist or format of a product
$query_search = "SELECT * FROM waxItem WHERE title OR artist LIKE  '%".$search_input."%'";

$query_search_result = mysql_query($query_search)
 or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows_search = mysql_num_rows($query_search_result);

?>
```

The code above does not work when i add "OR artist".

The code does work and search results are displayed when only one field is compared to the database records.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Question:  What happens when I enter "ZZ%'; DROP TABLE Users; --" into your searchbox?

Comment: PHP Developers and SQL Injection. Causation, not correlation.

Comment: @RBarryYoung nothing would happen as you can only have 1 query in the mysql_query function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I checked the documentation and it says `mysql_query` doesn't *support* multiple queries, not that only one ever executes. And for what it's worth, it's still vulnerable to `' OR 1 IN ( SELECT userID FROM Users, Users, Users, Users, Users, Users, Users, Users )`

Comment: I looked at [the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L1456), and it does disable multiple statements via `MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot state the same LIKE criteria for multiple fields. You have to specify it per field. Even though you can do this but this is definitely not a recommended approach due to SQL Injection Attacks. Please read this [**SQL Injection**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

You have to change

```
    $query_search = "SELECT * FROM waxItem WHERE title OR artist 
LIKE  '%".$search_input."%'";
```

to

```
        $query_search = "SELECT * FROM waxItem WHERE title 
LIKE '%".$search_input."%' OR artist LIKE  '%".$search_input."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a relation per field.

```
$query_search = "SELECT * FROM waxItem WHERE title LIKE '%".$search_input."%' OR artist LIKE '%".$search_input."%'";
```